# How to see DOM changes real time Chrome Dev Tool?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am not sure, but it appears that the JS changes does not reflect in the 'element' tab section as they are executed. I don't see changes like

```
document.write( '<script src="' + scriptSrc + '" type="text/javascript"><\/script>' );
```

If and how I am able to see JS changes real time in DOM from Chrome Dev Tool? If Chrome Dev tool doesn't provide this capability, what tool is there that does this?
Thank You for helping